# C# Winforms MVP-Passive View, where to handle the Model?

Tags: c#, winforms, model, mvp

I am new to the MVP-PV type of pattern and have some questions on how to handle the Models. (I am using simple CRUD statements in the app, not EF) Does the Model contain the CRUD that is used to retrieve data or just contain the properties for the model. Where do you instantiate the Model? In the View passed with the Presenter? At the top of the Presenter? In each method?

Here is a simple example of what I am doing with MVP.

The UserControl is added like this:

```
ElementView uControl = new ElementView()
uControl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
uControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
rPanel.Controls.Add(uControl);
```

The Interface:

```
namespace MPVExample.View
{
    public interface IElementView
    {
        int IElementPKey { get; set; }
        string INumber { get; set; }
        string IDescription { get; set; }

        event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnEditElement;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
namespace MPVExample.View
{
    public partial class ElementView : UserControl, IElementView
    {
        private ElementPresenter presenter = null;

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnEditElement;

        public int IElementPKey 
        {
            get { return TxtElementKey.Text; }
            set { TxtElementKey.Text = value; }
        }

        public string INumber
        {
            get { return TxtNumber.Text; }
            set { TxtNumber.Text = value; }
        }

        public string IDescription
        {
            get { return TxtDescription.Text; }
            set { TxtDescription.Text = value; }
        }

        public ElementView ()
        {
            presenter = new ElementPresenter(this);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnEditElement?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

The Presenter:

```
namespace MPVExample.Presenter
{
    public class ElementPresenter
    {
        private readonly IElementViewView;
        //ElementModel Model = new ElementModel (); //Instantiate Here?

        public ElementPresenter(IElementView view)
        {
            try
            {
                if (view != null)
                {
                    View = view;
                    Initialize();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("IElementView");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 //Log Error
            }
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                View.OnEditElement += Edit_Element;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 //Log Error
            }
        }

        private void Edit_Element(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
             ElementModel model = new ElementModel(); //Instantiate Here?
             Model.ElementPKey = View.IElementPKey;
             Model.Number = Convert.ToByte(View.INumber);
             Model.Description = View.IDescription;
             Model.Edit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 //Log Error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
namespace MPVExample.Models
{
    public class ElementModel 
    {
        public int ElementPKey { get; set; }
        public byte Number { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public void Edit() //Does this belong in here?
        {
             //SQL to Edit record
        }

        public void Save() //Does this belong in here?
        {
             //SQL to Save record
        }

        public void Get() //Does this belong in here?
        {
             //SQL to Get record
        }

        public void Delete() //Does this belong in here?
        {
             //SQL to Delete record
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Models should be initialized within the presenters**. It is better to initialize it at a single place and use it everywhere within the presenters. Views can call the presenter methods along with the parameters needed(mainly from GUI elements). Inside presenter methods, with all the parameters passed, you can use it and interact with the model object and perform get, edit, save, delete operations. In case you need to update the change in model to the view, you need to have methods, within the models that call methods in presenter, which will inturn call the methods in view which brings the UI updates.

For beginners, it can be confusing. Simply put, **every presenter** will have a reference to it's **view as well as the model**. **Every view** will have a reference to it's **presenter alone**. **Every model** will have reference to **presenters alone**, not the view. This way you can achieve loose coupling between the various layers of the application.

https://github.com/HewittVS/MVP-Pattern-CSharp

I have attached link to my github repository, containing a sample application using MVP pattern. But I haven't used models much. You can see how far we can change actual UI event methods in terms of presenter methods calls. Good Luck mate :)

Comment: Ideally **View** should not have any reference to a **Presenter**, as Model should not know about Presenter too. It is better to use an EventAggregator singleton to Publish events from View. And why Model should need to know about Presenter?